# htaccess 301 redirect with GET doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

What I want to achieve is the following:

URL /element.php?dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak should redirect to /ajankohtaista

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak
RewriteRule ^element\.php$ /ajankohtaista/? [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. Any clue what I am missing ?

EDIT: here is my full .htaccess:

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_environment_initialize() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak
  RewriteRule ^element\.php$ /ajankohtaista/? [L,R=301]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, try removing the `/?` from the RewriteRule.

Comment: it doesn't redirect. it stays at the same page. also after removing the /?

Comment: What do you mean, it stays at the same page? Do you mean you browse to `/element.php?dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak` and that is actually what appears in the address bar?

Comment: yes, exactly like that. i go to mysite/element.php?dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak and it tells me:  "page not found" , "The requested page "/element.php?dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak" could not be found. "

while, if I go directly to mysite/ajankohtaista, then it shows me this page that I expect to see

Comment: Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess?

Comment: added my full .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have `element.php` file anymore (it does **not** exist).
Because of that, it is rewritten to `index.php` regarding on your previous rule.
An easy solution would be to swap your two rules.

This part

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak
RewriteRule ^element\.php$ /ajankohtaista/? [L,R=301]
```

should be like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} dogtag=tdcf_tdcbusiness_ak
RewriteRule ^element\.php$ /ajankohtaista [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```